# Where can I store data in Wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development

I made a pretty straightforward API something like

```
$storage = new SettingsStorage($name, $schema);
$form = new SettingsForm($storage, $action, $fields);
$form->render();
```

I want to use the same approach everywhere in my plugins. For example currently I learn meta boxes and I want to do something like:

```
$storage = new PostMetaStorage($name, $schema);
$box = new MetaBox($storage, $action, $fields);
$box->render();
```

Can somebody write a short list about where I can store data in Wordpress?

What I already know is:

- Settings Options: register_setting, get_option, update_option, settings_fields
- Post Meta: add_meta_box, get_post_meta, update_post_meta

Comment: WordPress stores most if not all of its data in its database, using helper functions like, for example, [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) or [`update_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/). Can you [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/424186/edit), please, to clarify what you're actually asking? eg, do you want to know if you should be using `*_option` or `*_meta` functions?

Comment: @PatJ Just a list of the helper functions when storing data is involved. But I'll figure it out in the long run by using the manual. It would just make plugin development faster if somebody would write a short list.

Comment: In my experience, `update_option()` and `update_post_meta()` are what I need over 90% of the time. Use `update_option()` if you want to save data related to the site overall, and use `update_post_meta()` if you want to save data related to a specific post.

Comment: @PatJ Ohh thanks! I did not know it is all I need. Not sure what to do about the question. Maybe answer it with this or write about the 10% of the cases please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) and [`update_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) are what I need over 90% of the time. Use `update_option()` if you want to save data related to the site overall, and use `update_post_meta()` if you want to save data related to a specific post.

The other ~10% of the time I might need something more esoteric, like [`set_transient()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/) if I want to temporarily save some data (eg if I want to cache something) or [`wp_insert_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) if I want to add a new term to a taxonomy.